# Python function not accepting the second argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

Sample Data frame -

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'City':['York New', 'Parague', 'New Delhi', 'Venice', 'new Orleans'],
                    'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy', 'Tech_Summit'],
                    'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000, 12000]})
  
index_ = [pd.Period('02-2018'), pd.Period('04-2018'),
          pd.Period('06-2018'), pd.Period('10-2018'), pd.Period('12-2018')]
  
df.index = index_
print(df)
```

Problem Statement - For those cities which starts with the keyword ‘New’ or ‘new’, change it to ‘New_’

First I have created a new column in the dataframe to find if the City has "new" in the name and if yes then at what position

```py
df["pos"] = df["City"].apply(lambda x: x.lower().find("new"))
```

Then I have created a function to replace "New" or "new" by "New_" if they are present in the starting of the city name -

```py
def replace_new(city,pos):
    if pos==0:
        return city.replace("[Nn]ew", "New_", regex = True)
    else:
        return city

df = df[["City","pos"]].apply(replace_new, axis = 1)
```

When I execute the above code line I am getting this error -
`"("replace_new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pos'", 'occurred at index 2018-02')"`

What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Comment: Why is this tagged R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.replace` with a regex:

```py
df['City'] = df['City'].str.replace(r'^new\s*', 'New_', case=False, regex=True)
```

output:

```
                City        Event   Cost
2018-02     York New        Music  10000
2018-04      Parague       Poetry   5000
2018-06    New_Delhi      Theatre  15000
2018-10       Venice       Comedy   2000
2018-12  New_Orleans  Tech_Summit  12000
```

regex:

```
^       # match start of line
new     # match "new"
\s*     # match zero or more spaces
```

Comment: You should probably have used: `.apply(lambda x: replace_new(x['City'], x['Pos']), axis = 1)` or gotten the full row as argument. But this is a bad way to do it in pandas. `apply` is unnecessary and slow here.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. I understand regex is much more efficient. Still wanted to know why my function is no working. Anyway, thanks again

Comment: The question is rather, why did you think it should work? Also, you can't use a regex in `str.replace`.

Comment: The error I am getting says - "replace_new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pos'". But while invoking the function I have given the argument. So I want to know why this error. What am I missing here?

Comment: No, apply passes only **one** argument: the row as Series, not several.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method this way

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: replace_new(x.City, x.pos), axis=1)
```

Also the replace method is not working properly use Re

```
import re
def replace_new(city,pos):
    if pos==0:
        return re.sub('[Nn]ew', 'New_', city)
    else:
        return city
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just wondering why my code didn't work.

Comment: Because the df[["City","pos"]].apply(replace_new, axis = 1) is trying to apply the method on both columns of data separetly like replace_new(city) and replace_new(pos). and in both cases one argument is missing. which is mentioned in the error.